# convert video without losing frames and have same fps and tbr using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

My original video "test1.mp4" has following properties

```
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 283 kb/s, 34.55 fps, 50 tbr, 50k tbn, 50 tbc (default).
```

I got it from running `ffmpeg -i test1.mp4`.

I had to change the video codec to `h264`. So I converted the above video using below command

`ffmpeg -i test1.mp4 test1.mp4`.

However the props of the converted video has changed. fps is 50 and tbr is 50. And also frame count has increased compared to original video.

```
 Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 114 kb/s, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 12800 tbn, 100 tbc (default)
```

After following this link https://superuser.com/questions/1307863/why-is-ffmpeg-changing-framerate-from-60-to-120,  I found that ffmpeg uses `tbr` values instead of `fps` while converting in order to not to lose any frames but at the cost of duplicate frames. As suggested in the link above I used `vsync 0` option while converting video.

```
ffmpeg -i test1.mp4 -vsync 0 test1_sync.mp4.
```

Now the Frame count is same as the input video (checked using `ffprobe`). But the `fps` is still little different from the original video.

```
 Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 61 kb/s, 12.88 fps, 50 tbr, 12800 tbn, 100 tbc (default).
```

How come frame count remains same even when fps is different?

To my use case I need the converted video to have same number of frames at the same timestamps as the original video, i just need the codec to be changed to `h264`. I dont want duplicate or losing frames.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

with -r you can indicate the fps

```
ffmpeg -i test1.mp4 -r 34.55 test1_sync.mp4
```

> Duration: 00:00:54.18, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 273 kb/s
> Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 202x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 101:180], 269 kb/s, 34.55 fps, 34.55 tbr, 11056 tbn, 69.10 tbc (default)